# How to get full downloadUrl from UploadTaskSnapshot in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I correctly receive `UploadTaskSnapshot`, and the field downloadUrl contains an instance of `Uri` that parses download link of uploaded file.

How to get storage and downloadUrl as strings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**old**

```
final uploadTask = imageStore.putFile(imageFile);
final url = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
```

**update**

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52690889/217408 is now the accurate one.

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('path')
    .child('to')
    .child('the')
    .child('image_filejpg');

ref.putFile(imageFile);
// or ref.putData(Uint8List.fromList(imageData));

var url = await ref.getDownloadURL() as String;
```

or

```
var url = Uri.parse(await ref.getDownloadURL() as String);
```

Comment: How to get string url out of that URI that downloadUrl returns.

Comment: `var urlString = url.toString()` or `var urlString = '${url}'`

Comment: Uri parses firebase tokens ect.. and I dont know how to get full url.
Also, that only answers half of the question. Is there a way to get storage location?

Comment: Thank you, though

Comment: Why would you need the storage location? That's what you need to have already before you can upload (`imageStore.path`)

Comment: because as a path I send only relative path, so looks like I need to hardcode base url in the app. I did it that way in the end.

Comment: Path relative to what? I don't get what the actual problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: when you upload the file you do `      StorageUploadTask putFile =
          storage.ref().child("region/$fileName").putFile(_regionImage);
` but the actual storage path is `"gs://app-db.appspot.com/region/$fileName";` Just thought that I can avoid hardcoding this url. Uri solution worked so thank you

Comment: When using it, it indicates the following: The getter 'future' isn't defined for the class StorageUploadTask

Comment: @DomingoMG try `flutter clean`. Otherwise I don't know. Doesn't look like the code I posted can produce such an error.

Comment: See new answer below

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: is there any ways to get all file in folder by using flutter ? So far, the answer which I know is NO. I need to get all files by file's name which was stored before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know this is also not possible in other languages. This is a Firebase limitation (not sure if this limitation was fixed in Firebase since). When I run into that I used insert and delete triggers with cloud functions to create/delete Firebase database records that point to files to be able to query.

Comment: The above way has been deprecated, to get the `url` check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64764390/7015400

Answer (score 7):

I get `downloadUrl` from v1.0.3 by the following code.

```
StorageReference storageReference = _storage.ref().child(path);
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFile);

StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Answer (score 6):

@DomingoMG it looks like with the latest release they want:

```
String location = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage#-example-tab-

Comment: What is the `ref` please explain better, I'm having issues getting the Download URL.

Comment: StorageReference. Go to link and search getDownloadURL

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Nov 2020**

`onComplete` is now removed from the upload task. So, use:

```
var reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("your_path");
await reference.putFile(fileToUpload);
var url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: how about getting a list of multi uploaded images?

Answer (score 0):

With the version of firebase_storage: ^11.0.11.
It worked this way:

```
final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  DocumentReference get firestoreRef => firestore.doc('products/$id');
  Reference get storageRef => storage.ref().child('products').child(id!);
```

> 

```
final UploadTask task = storageRef.child(const Uuid().v1()).putFile(newImage as File);
    final TaskSnapshot snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() {});
    final String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    updateImages.add(url);
```

OBS: I'm using package uuid: ^3.0.7 to create a random id for each upload