# Why UploadTaskSnapshot suddenly becomes an compilation error

Tags: ios, flutter

My Flutter app was working yesterday and today it is not.

Suddenly, error below:

> Error: 'UploadTaskSnapshot' isn't a type

Code:

```
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
            compressedFile,
            new StorageMetadata(
              contentLanguage: 'en',
              customMetadata: <String, String>{
                'pb': 'user_photo',
                'datemodified': new DateTime.now().toString(),
                },
            ),
          );
          print("Start upload");
          UploadTaskSnapshot uploadSnapshot = await uploadTask.future;

          print("image uploaded");
```

What actually happened?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404310/how-to-get-full-downloadurl-from-uploadtasksnapshot-in-flutter/50404432#50404432

Answer (score 1):

The last update from yesterday broke some things , they didn't mention on the changelog :  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage#-changelog-tab-

You can force one version before, using:

firebase_storage: "1.0.2"