# "Could not convert: Instance of '_Uri'" error while uploading image on cloud firestore's latest version on flutter web

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

Getting below error while using the latest version of `cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2` while uploading image on cloud firestore.

```dart
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Invalid argument (dartObject): Could not convert: Instance of '_Uri'
```

The image gets successfully uploaded in the storage portion but the image link doesn't get updated in cloud firestore db.

Below is the class from where I pick the image and and hit he upload btn to upload the image

```dart
class AddNewItemView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddNewItemViewState createState() => _AddNewItemViewState();
}

class _AddNewItemViewState extends State<AddNewItemView> {
  MediaInfo _itemPic; 
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    .....
    child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: () async {
              MediaInfo pickedImg =  await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo; <---- image_picker_web package
               setState(() {
                 _itemPic = pickedImg;
                });
    .........
    FlatButton(
         onPressed: () async {
            bool addDataSuccess = await model.addNewItem( _itemPic);
            if (addDataSuccess) {
                 print("Inside addDataSuccess");
            } else {
                 print("Outside addDataSuccess");
                   }
                 },
              ),
    .....
    );
}
```

This class is responsible for extracting image uri from `uploadImageFile` funtion and uploading it in `cloud firestore`.
Any other info passed alongside pic gets uploaded in cloud firestore, only 'pic' is not uploading

```dart
class ItemViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
           Future<bool> addNewItem(   MediaInfo pic ) async {
         
                 Uri _uploadedImgURL = await ConstantFtns()
                     .uploadImageFile(pic, "ImgPathString", "fileName");


     await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('item').doc("tempID").set(
        {
              'pic': _uploadedImgURL,
          'otherInfo': 'otherTempInfo' 
    },
        );
}
```

in below class  I get valid `imageUri` without any error and image gets uploaded in storage portion only problem is that it don't get uploaded in cloud firestore database

```dart
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:mime_type/mime_type.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

class ConstantFtns  {
  Future<Uri> uploadImageFile(
      MediaInfo mediaInfo, String ref, String fileName) async {
    try {
      String mimeType = mime(p.basename(mediaInfo.fileName));
       final String extension = extensionFromMime(mimeType);

      var metadata = fb.UploadMetadata(
        contentType: mimeType,
      );

      fb.StorageReference storageReference =
          fb.storage().ref(ref).child(fileName + ".$extension");

      fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot =
          await storageReference.put(mediaInfo.data, metadata).future;

      Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      print("download url $imageUri");  <---- IT GETS P[RINTED AND IT SHOWED VALED IMAGE URL STORED IN STORAGE
      return imageUri;
    } catch (e) {
      print("File Upload Error $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is simply to store the URL into firestore you don't really need the `getDownloadURL()` value to be a `Uri` object, you just need it's string value, being the error you are getting a conversion error, I suggest that you follow what is recommended in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404432/12857703), that way your code will look like this:

```
String uploadImageFile(
    MediaInfo mediaInfo, String ref, String fileName) async {
        try {
            ...

            var imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL() as String;
            print("download url $imageUri");  <---- IT GETS P[RINTED AND IT SHOWED VALED IMAGE URL STORED IN STORAGE
            return imageUri
        } catch (e) {
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

And you also have to change the call in the `ItemViewModel` class to:

```
String _uploadedImgURL = await ConstantFtns()
                 .uploadImageFile(pic, "ImgPathString", "fileName");
```